# Javascript loop addition

Tags: javascript, html

Good day guys. i just would like to ask something. i need to add the variable after i input a number.i really don't know how to do that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<input type="number" id="userNumber">
<input type="button" id="doFunction" value="Submit Number">

<script>
var number=document.getElementById('userNumber');

var button=document.getElementById('doFunction');
var textNumber;



button.onclick=function(){

for(var i=0; i < number.value; i++){
    textNumber=document.createTextNode(i+1);
    document.body.appendChild(textNumber);
}

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i want the out put should be ( i enter 5 )

1
2
3
4
5

sum = 15

Comment: this code has no errors. what output you are expecting. post an example.

Comment: What do u mean add variable? Can u please explain in more details?

Comment: i enter a number.. after. then all the number displayed will be added together. for exmaple i hit 5. the output shoul be ( 1 2 3 4 5 / sum = 15 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use closures. Also, instead of using `text nodes`, you may use `inner html`

Check out the fiddle for ideas. http://jsfiddle.net/FU3P6/

```
(function() {
    var oIn = document.getElementById('in');
    var oGo = document.getElementById('do');
    var oRs = document.getElementById('rs');
    oGo.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var nCount = 0, nSum = 0;
        var oCount, oSum;
        while(nCount < oIn.value) {
            nCount += 1;
            oCount = document.createTextNode(nCount + " ");
            oRs.appendChild(oCount);
            nSum += nCount;
        }
        oSum = document.createTextNode('Sum: ' + nSum);
        oRs.appendChild(oSum);
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want this (Need to put the `onclick` event handler in a `load` event)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var number=document.getElementById('userNumber');
    var button=document.getElementById('doFunction');
    button.onclick=function(){
        for(var i=0; i < number.value; i++){
            var textNumber = document.createTextNode(i+1);
            document.body.appendChild(textNumber);
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JmUA9/1/)

**Update :**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var number=document.getElementById('userNumber');
    var button=document.getElementById('doFunction');
    button.onclick=function(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < number.value; i++){
            var textNumber = document.createTextNode(i+1);
            document.body.appendChild(textNumber);
            sum +=(i+1);
        }
        var textNumber = document.createTextNode(sum);
        var slash = document.createTextNode(' / ');
        document.body.appendChild(slash);
        document.body.appendChild(textNumber);
    }
});
```

[**Updated Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JmUA9/2/)

Comment: tnx master..for the last time..how to multiply them all? :)

Comment: @RonneilFernandezPejante, [Check this.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JmUA9/3/).

Comment: nice master..but to show both sum and product?

Comment: You have got the idea, figure it out and next time please ask the question in a more clear/specific way.

Comment: i got it master.. thx

Comment: Really glad to know that. Take Care and we all are developers here, each one help each other, so no `master`! :-)